# Impossible to mount an external hard drive on mac after bug

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount

I made a mistake by plugging my external WD hard drive with my GoPro link (they look like the same). Everything was working, and, during a file transfer, my hard drive disappeared from my MacBook Pro, then, impossible to mount it.

I bought a new box to put my hard drive, nothing to do. It appears in the Disk utilities, it appears with the Terminal command `diskutil list`.

I tried `diskutil info /dev/disk2` and the result is the following :

```
Device Identifier:        disk2
   Device Node:              /dev/disk2
   Part of Whole:            disk2
   Device / Media Name:      WDC WD75 00AAVS-00D7B1 Media

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      FDisk_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported

   Total Size:               750.2 GB (750156374016 Bytes) (exactly 1465149168 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

And the command `diskutil list disk2` :

```
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 My Book                 750.2 GB   disk2s1
```

I don't know what I can do... it's been 6 months I have this problem, I tried everything (everything I found out) but nothing worked. There are all my virtual life inside, and professional one, I would love to recover it.

Thanks by advance and sorry for my English ;)

Comment: Looks like the file-system got corrupted.  Most likely either the drive is failing, or it was due to an improper disconnect of the drive while writing to it. Use recovery software to attempt the data recovery.

Comment: Thanks ! Do you have any working software to recommend me ?

Comment: Thank you very much @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, I'm trying the PhotoRec solution :) I will tell you when it will be over !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Techie007 thank you so much ! It worked very well ! So, here is my solution :

I went on http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step#Run_PhotoRec_executable, downloaded the software PhotoRec, followed the steps (simple, really well explained on the wiki) !

Now, I'm recovering everything. It's written 40 hours left, but for the moment, I already recovered 7000 files ! So good !!!

Thanks a lot one more time !